# How to extract records at position x from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails (or Ruby), is it possible to target and manipulate items at a certain position within an array.

For example, say I have defined an array that cannot exceed 10 records.

```
@array = Model.where(:my_query = something).order(:my_order).first(10)
```

Now I want to do something with the first 5 records, and something else with the last five. I could use

```
@array.first(5)
@array.last(5)
```

but this falls apart if `:my_query` returns less than 10 records—i.e. there will be overlap.

```
@array.at(1)
```

returns a single position, but what if I need a range of positions. I'm looking for something like

```
@array.position(1..5)
@array.position(6..10)
```

Does something like this exist? I'm not sure what search terms I should be Googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
first = @array[0..4]
last = @array[5..9]
```

That will return the first five and the last five elements from the array in two separate variables. If you do it this way and you will not get any overlap.

Comment: thanks @ryan, this looks promising. how can I ensure that empty arrays don't cause an error using this approach. e.g. if `@array` contains only 3 records. `@array[0..4]` will display all records. `@array[5..9].each do |array|` raises `undefined method 'each' for nil`

Comment: never mind. `unless .empty?` is the ticket. I never knew positions could be defined in arrays in this manner. Much more simple than I was making it! Thanks!